# The area of the range of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $D=\{z;|z|\leq r\}$. Then the area of $f(D)$ is
$$\int_0^{2\pi}u(\theta)v'(\theta)d \theta,$$
where 
$$u(\theta)=\Re f(re^{i\theta}),\ v(\theta)=\Im f(re^{i\theta}.)$$

I could not derive it. But only know that the area is
$$\iint_{|z|\leq r}|f'(z)|^2dxdy=\int_0^r \int_0^{2\pi}(u_r^2+v_r^2)rd\theta dr.$$

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I have got it. We just need to use the Green's formula. 
$$Area=\iint_Ddudv=\int_{\partial D}udv.$$